# Understanding mod_rewrite regular expressions

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got the following messy URL:

```
http://localhost/writer/show?post_url=1rk8wy0h4
```

However, I would like it to change to:

```
http://localhost/writer/show/1rk8wy0h4
```

This is the regular expression that finds the messy part of the URL:

```
/\?post_url=/
```

What would be the best way for me to use this expression so it replaces it with a simple `/`?

My current `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

And this is how I did it with JavaScript

```
s = s.replace(/\?post_url=/, '/');
```

But I'm unsure how to replace with mod_rewrite.

What is the mod_rewrite equivalent?

Comment: Do you want to convert a pretty URL into an ugly one? Why?

Comment: Sorry, the opposite. Ugly to pretty.

Comment: Then you need to convert /writer/show/1rk8wy0h4 into /writer/show?post_url=1rk8wy0h4

Comment: You can try your rewrite rules easily here: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Comment: Where is located your htaccess (in which folder) ? Also, is `show` an existing file or a symlink ?

Comment: htaccess is in the /writer/ folder, and `/show` is a file that runs the query eg `/show.php?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's similar but you want to be matching against the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable. So something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+writer/show\?post_url=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /writer/show/%1? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^show/(.+)$ /writer/show?post_url=$1 [L]
```

those rules would need to be in your *writer folder*.

Comment: Thanks. Each $_GET request seems to end in .php now? `post_url=1rk8wy0h4` is now `post_url=1rk8wy0h4.php`

Comment: @tmyie your other rule is doing that, you need to add these rules *before* the rule you have that adds a .php to the end of every request

Comment: I can't find much documentation on ` %{THE_REQUEST}`, what does it do?

Comment: @tmyie It's the first line of an HTTP request, looks something like: `GET /path/to/file.php?param=value HTTP/1.1`. It's the unadulterated request. The URI gets modified as the rules get applied (among other reasons), so you can check against `%{THE_REQUEST}` to see what the original, unmodified, request looks like. In this case, we need to know the request was *actually for the URI with the query string*.